# Can't extends imported class

Tags: flowtype

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

the code above work fine but when I try to do the same with an imported class, I't does not work.

```
declare module 'a' {
  declare export class A {}
}

import typeof { A } from 'a';

class B extends A {}
```

> Cannot reference type `A` [1] from a value position

can anyone solve this ?

https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBByKX4G8AoeeUSWBEADwAdkYAXecgZxfgEECBfQ3wgJaI6jeAwCeNEMgBmBTvG4ACmTGSJ4OLAG5ChVuwBC8agxAA7YOy75uQA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a class you actually define both a type and a Javascript class, and both have the same name. Types only exist at compile time - they have no runtime representation. In your example you imported the type, but not the runtime value.

```
 // imports the type only
import typeof { A } from 'a'

 // imports both the type and the runtime value
import { A } from 'a'
```

The type informs Flow what the class does for purposes of type checking. But the runtime value is what defines the implementation to be executed. The compiled program must have a reference to the runtime value to instantiate or to extend a class. In other words, remove the `typeof` keyword and it should work.